# How to create Firebase push notifications group in React Native?

Tags: firebase, react-native

I get a problem using Firebase to create push notifications group in React Native, when I receive many push notifications I want to create it to be 1 group like WhatsApp (like red circle in image below).

[image]

I have tried to look for many examples but I didn't found a solution. Please anyone help me to create like that.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

use [react-native-push-notification](https://github.com/zo0r/react-native-push-notification)

// create channel

```
import PushNotification, {Importance} from 'react-native-push-notification';
...
  PushNotification.createChannel(
    {
      channelId: "channel-id", // (required)
      channelName: "My channel", // (required)
      channelDescription: "A channel to categorise your notifications", // (optional) default: undefined.
      playSound: false, // (optional) default: true
      soundName: "default", // (optional) See `soundName` parameter of `localNotification` function
      importance: Importance.HIGH, // (optional) default: Importance.HIGH. Int value of the Android notification importance
      vibrate: true, // (optional) default: true. Creates the default vibration pattern if true.
    },
    (created) => console.log(`createChannel returned '${created}'`) // (optional) callback returns whether the channel was created, false means it already existed.
  );
```

// this shows each new notification for a while then pushes it into group

```
PushNotification.localNotification({
      channelId: 'channel-id',
      title: `New message`,
      message: 'Hello world',
})
```

// this groups messages

```
PushNotification.localNotification({
      channelId: 'channel-id',
      id: 'messages',
      group: 'messages',
      groupSummary: true
})
```